# Set system properties for Android application

Tags: android, configuration, android-manifest, system-properties

Can I (in the Manifest file or somewhere else) set system properties for my Android application?

I want to use a library that can be configured using system properties, and being able to just use that mechanism would reduce the amount of code I need to write.

Comment: Android seems to have no equivalent to the [java -D option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI) for presetting a system property before the code runs, e.g. no manifest directive. Other negative answers about the java option approach: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037234) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316622).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can set system properties for your app.

```
String myprop;
System.setProperty("MYPROP", "4");
myprop = System.getProperty("MYPROP");
Log.i(TAG, "MYPROP: " + myprop);
```

Here, you set and geta system property from the Java "world". To access it from the C/C++ world (NDK), ie your lib, check out this post:
[Calling a java method from c++ in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android).

Comment: Yes, but that would be in code. I want to reduce the amount of code that I need to write by having it in a file somewhere. (Of course, your suggestions makes it possible for me to write a small helper class that sets properties from a file)