# Does Android VM have any command line options?

Tags: java, android, virtual-machine

Does Android VM have any command line options?  If it has, how can I set them in eclipse?

I'm looking something like this:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

but for dalvik.

How can I use the `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` parameter?

Comment: http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/hello-world.html ... but i do not know i dalvikvm can use such parameter ...

Answer (score 2):

I found the following [in this link](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/embedded-vm-control.html) searching at Google:

> The Dalvik VM supports a variety of command-line arguments (use adb shell dalvikvm -help to get a summary), but it's not possible to pass arbitrary arguments through the Android application runtime. It is, however, possible to affect the VM behavior through certain system properties.

But this is only through adb.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

The Dalvik does not have any command lines such as the oracle article you mention.

There're thou a few Manifest parameters that you can use to request simple stuff such as larger memory, hardware accelerated, etc.