# How to pass JVM arguments in eclipse for Android programs?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to pass this to my Android app so I will get null pointer stacktraces:

```
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

(From other stackoverflow question)
This guide shows how to do it, BUT the arguments tab is NOT there for an android app, only normal java apps:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Farguments.htm

So how do I do it for Android apps or should I do something completely different?

Comment: You already get a stack trace for a `NullPointerException` in LogCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not going to work.  That is a command line argument for a JVM.  Android doesn't have a JVM.  In Android, your bytecodes are executed by Dalvik, a virtual machine that is quite, quite different.

One of the ways in which it is different is that it is started, more or less, when your phone boots.  Even if it did recognize that particular command line argument, when your application starts, Dalvik has already been running for a while.  You can't pass a command line argument.

Comment: I see... any way I can get the stacktrace then?

Comment: Sure!  As @CommonsWare says, look in your Logcat