# How to call Java from NDK C++?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to call various Java functions while in native C++ to do some stuff (loading gfx, etc...) and would like to know how. Does anyone of you know some samples or have a few helpful code snippets ?

Comment: Try to use search:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android

Comment: I used the search but must have missed that. Anyway, that was exactly what I was looking for and it works, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

To call Java functions from NDK you have to use JNI.

A useful and simple example is provided at the following link:

[Invoke Java from C/C++](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/)

But I suggest that you should:

- **Not** create a new Java Virtual Machine as in the above example. Instead you should use the JavaVM* and JNIEnv* that you get when you call the NDK functions.
- Be careful for memory leaks when you use NDK.