# calling java from native c++ JNI DIRECTLY

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This question has been asked and answered in many posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android)!

But how can I call from c++ directly ? For this how can I get JNIEnv* and jobject ?
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

To get `JNIEnv` you can write global `JNI_OnLoad` function that will get called during loading of shared library. This function will get `JavaVM` pointer as argument. Using it you can get `JNIEnv` for current thread (or create new one if there was no `JNIEnv` previously).

As to where get jobject - if that is new object you are instantiating, then you use `JNIEnv::NewObject` method. Otherwise you need to pass object on which you want to call method from java side to C/C++.

Comment: What shared library? He is calling directly from C.

Comment: What is "directly from C"? If you want to run your C code on Android then you must put C code in shared library - that is the only officially supported way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [Invocation section of the JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502).