# Calling a JAVA method from C++ with JNI, no parameters

Tags: java, android, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

Please bear with me, I am an iPhone developer and this whole android this confuses me a bit.

I have some c++ methods that are called from a cocos2d-x CCMenuItem. Therefore I cannot send any parameters, according to the docs.

I need to open a url with the android browser which will require me to call a JAVA function to start a new intent.

I understand that I need to create a VM, however the below code gives me the error:

> jni/../../Classes/OptionsScene.cpp:184: error: 'JNI_CreateJavaVM' was
>   not declared in this scope

I was looking at this thread: [Calling a java method from c++ in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android)

But he uses parameters, and I can't do that. And I don't see where those are in his code to just make them myself.

I don't know what the string should be in the 'Find Class' method.
Also, I assume it is pretty terrible to create a new VM instance in every method I need to call. How would I create one as a singleton to use across the board?

This is my c++ code called by my menu item:

```
#include <jni.h>
...
JavaVM *vm; // Global
...
void OptionsScene::website(){
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
vm_args.nOptions = 0;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 1;

jint result = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args); // This line still errors

jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/prndl/project/WebExecute");
jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "website", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(NULL,method);

vm->DestroyJavaVM();
```

And this is the JAVA Method that I need to call:

```
public class WebExecute extends Activity{
    public void website(){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

Honestly, I am struggling with this, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What lines do you get errors on now?  Just the `JNI_CreateJavaVM` one or others as well?  Have you double-checked your compiler/IDE settings to make sure that the `JDK_HOME/include` directory (which contains `jni.h`) is in the includes search path?  Same for the `JDK_HOME/include/android` directory (or whatever the operating specific directory in `JDK_HOME/include` is called in a Android JDK)?

Comment: Were you getting a compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of things...

1. Given the declaration `JNIEnv* env;`, and given that you're in C++, you use it as `env->FindClass(someString)`, **not** how you're doing it.  If it was C you'd use `FindClass(env, someString)` but in C++ you use `env->FindClass(someString)`.
2. The string to use in `FindClass` is the fully qualified path name but with `/` as the delimiter instead of `.`  For example, if the class is `Foo` in package `bar.baz.quux`, the fully-qualified name is `bar.baz.quux.Foo` and the string you'd give to `FindClass` is `bar/baz/quux/Foo`.
3. You can only create one JVM per C++ process.  I'm pretty sure you need to create a single JVM one time.  You will therefore need to have the `JavaVM* vm` be a global variable (or at least be somewhere accessible to everything that needs to use.  Everything in the same C++ thread as the thread that called `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` will use the `JNIEnv *` that gets filled in by that call.  Every other thread that wants to use the JVM needs to call `AttachCurrentThread` which will bind that thread to the JVM and fill in a *new* `JNIEnv *` valid for that thread.
4. Have you double-checked your compiler/IDE settings to make sure that the `JDK_HOME/include` directory (which contains `jni.h`) is in the includes search path?  Same for the `JDK_HOME/include/android` directory (or whatever the operating specific directory in `JDK_HOME/include` is called in a Android JDK)?

A very useful resource is [The JNI book](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/download/jni.pdf)

But be careful while reading it because some examples are in C and some are in C++, so make sure you understand how the calling conventions differ.

Comment: I updated my original code above. It still says that JNI_CreateJavaVM is not declared in this scope, even though I have included jni.h. Also, since I do not have a parameter for website(), was I supposed to use NULL as the first parameter of env->CallVoidMethod()?

Comment: Some experimentation with `g++` on Linux indicates the `void **` stuff is a red herring (I'm rusty on C++).  As I test I declared `void foo(void *)` function and then called it like this: `int i = 42; foo(&i);` and the compiler didn't even give a warning, let alone an error.  So I don't think the presence or absence of the `void **` cast is relevant.

Comment: The `website `method doesn't have parameters so the type signature should be `"()V"` not `"(Ljava/lang/String;)V"`

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking at how to call a java method which does not take in any arguments, the format is `jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(myClass, "myMethod", "()V");`

`()` is how you tell it does not take in any params.

`V`says it returns void. `Ljava/lang/String;`should be used if the method returns an object of type `String`.