# Android callback examples using SWIG

Tags: android, callback, java-native-interface, swig

Does anybody have a decent example on how to introduce callback functionality in an Android app that uses native code? Ideally, I would like to use swig to generate the interface. Website links?

Comment: I can only tell about callback and by using interfaces...

Comment: I think you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android

Comment: ok, think we misunderstood each other...I meant callback from native code. I want to call java code from native code...thanks anyway.

Comment: ok ok ok.. now i understand... i am not a native programmer but check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android