# Android How to Call Java method from Jni with int and int[] parameters?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to call the Java method from Jni code with the int and int[] arguments. for that i have Go-ogled and found the following sample .
[Calling a java method from c++ in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android)
 And it worked fine with  String parameter . But While trying with int i got issues . 
Please help me .

**JNI CODE:**

```
jstring Java_com_calljavafromjni_MainActivity_getJniString( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj){

    jstring jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "RAJESH TEST from JNI ");
    jint sss=1111;
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/calljavafromjni/MainActivity");


    jmethodID messageMe = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "messageMe", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Integer;");
    jobject result = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, messageMe, sss);

   const char* str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,(jstring) result, NULL); // should be released but what a heck, it's a tutorial :)
    printf("%s\n", str);

   return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str);


}
```

Java code

```
public String messageMe(Integer text) {
    System.out.println( "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa "+text);

    return "test";
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the Java method you want to call, and how you are trying to call it? The [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) really does contain everything you need to know, its just not always easy to work out what you need.

Comment: i have updated java method in update .

Comment: And you expect the output to be `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 1111` ? Where do int[] come in?

Comment: Let us know if you managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see where `int[]` come into your problem, but with `int` it should be easy to solve.

You need to look at your `GetMethodId()` call, specifically the method signature argument (the last one). The JNI Specification provides a list of all its [Type Signatures here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432). That should also help you when you eventually come to pass your int arrays too.

So we can see at the moment your signature is:

`String messageMe(Integer text)`

but you told JNI it was `(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Integer;` which translates to something like:

`java.lang.Integer messageMe(String text)`

The [Type Signatures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432) show us that the signature for an `int` is simply `I` so your argument for `GetMethodId()` should be something like this:

`jmethodID messageMe = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "messageMe", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;");`

I hope that helps. As I said before, JNI isn't the easiest thing to get into but the answers really are all in the [Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html), you just have to look quite hard.

**EDIT:** I corrected my signature.

Basically, you were almost there - you just got the arguments and return value the wrong way around in the signature. It should be `(<arguments>)<return type>`. You also made the easy mistake of specifying the class for Integer, instead of the primitive type.