# How can I access to the camera with native codes on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera

For some reason, I have got to access the camera device with native codes on an Android device. Specifically, I would like to get the camera buffer in the form of an RGB color array. My question is:

1. Are there any native Android APIs I can use for this?
2. Can I access the camera without using Android APIs, if possible?

Any comments, including site links, would be very helpful to me.

Comment: This is the class used in pre-21-API-level development http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html. There is a new class for Lollipop http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

As for the question about accessing camera hardware without API I don't think it's possible

Comment: Camera access has to go through the Native Java Android APIs. If you need to use C/C++, you can, but you would still need to use JNI to go through those Java APIs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android?lq=1