# Invoke intent through NDK and get the result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk

I am trying to get an image path through NDK using an intent in Android.
I have the intent below that will pick an image from a Gallery. How can I invoke it through NDK and get the result back in C++? The code below is part of my MainActivity class.

```
public void pickImage(Activity activity) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 200 );
}

String selectedFilePath = "";

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri path = data.getData();
    selectedFilePath = path.toString();

}

public String getUserSelectedFile() {
    return selectedFilePath;
}
```

On the C++ side I can call the intent using the code below but how can I get the result from onActivityResult? What I am getting on the first run is empty string from selectedFilePath, but when I call the intent second time I am getting the string from before. I think that pickImage is blocking getUserSelectedFile.

```
jclass clazz(env->GetObjectClass(activity));
jmethodID method_id = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "pickImage", "()V");
env->CallVoidMethod(activity, method_id);

jmethodID method_id2 = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "getUserSelectedFile", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(activity, method_id2);
const char *strReturn = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring) result, 0);
```

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198105/calling-a-java-method-from-c-in-android. not just the accepted answer but others as well. You can see how to pass data both ways

Comment: It doesn't explain how to get Activity result.

Comment: yes, it does. Specifically, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35976648/3866010. You find the class, you find the method, you call that method and method returns an object. So your behavior should be that once user picks the image after you call that intent, you save the image's path for now and you call a fake C/C++ method that will invoke a java method shown in that example

Comment: Calling the function as void is fine but what I am trying to get is the result from onActivityResult.

Comment: I posted a very simple example. see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working for you is that you need to have a SECOND native method for the code I gave above. That second native method, you can call from onActivityResult() AFTER user selects the file. That means when the getUserSelectedFile() is called, the String will already have the value.

Note: Answer is edited few times based on comments below.

In your activity:

```
String selectedFilePath = "";

static {
    System.loadLibrary("your_lib_name");
}

public native void getImagePath();

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        selectedFilePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
        cursor.close();
        getImagePath();  // this is your native method that will invoke getUserSelectedFile()
    }
}

public void pickImage(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 200 );
}

private static String getUserSelectedFile() {
    return selectedFilePath;
}
```

Then in native (C/C++), you need these two methods:

```
void Java_com_my_package_name_pickImage(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass clazz(env->GetObjectClass(activity));
    jmethodID method_id = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "pickImage", "()V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(activity, method_id);
}

void Java_com_my_package_name_getImagePath(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass clazz(env->GetObjectClass(activity));
    jmethodID method_id2 = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "getUserSelectedFile", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(activity, method_id2);
    const char *strReturn = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring) result, 0);
}
```

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: The problem with this solution It doesn't act as a callback. What I am getting is empty string when I invoke it second time I am getting the string from before. Basically I am calling "pickImage" and "getUserSelectedFile" inside the same function in C++.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post what you tried? thanks

Comment: @sabotage3d thanks for editing your question. I've edited my answer. re-read all because I added comments in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Can you please make a slighly more clear example I can't get it to work?

Comment: Try now. You should really read a little more here to help you understand more. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI

Comment: Thanks I already was doing something similar just wanted to check the correct way.