# Create object of the activity class

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, startactivityforresult

I tried to gete callback from the created activity using [Invoke intent through NDK and get the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333616/invoke-intent-through-ndk-and-get-the-result)

But i have some problems.

I create a new activity using "startActivityForResult" method. So, object of this class creating in the start activity moment, and I can't get this object (for example, to call some methods).

I tried to create a new object without "starting" activity using:

```
WCHAR_T* className = 0;
convToShortWchar(&className, L"myPackage.myActivity");
jclass ccloc = helper->FindClass(className);
jmethodID activityInit = env->GetMethodID(ccloc, "<init>", "()V");
jobject activityObj = env->NewObject(ccloc, activityInit);
```

Program is crashed at the last line. activityInit and ccloc is not NULL.

myPackage.myActivity in the Java code is:

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaymentControllerListener{
...
}
```

There are exists onCreate method, constructor is not overidden.

Please, help, how can i take my Activity object to start a new activity with intent and take its result?

Comment: Crashed in what way? Have you tried using a debugger or at least looked at the log output?

Comment: idk how to tune visual studio to debug dynamic library. There are some problems with debugging: library is started by 1C Enterprise, so, i can't to manage that process. And i dont understand how it is working...

Comment: What does `helper->FindClass` do ?

Comment: Also, why are you creating activities by hand? Is that even documented to work?