# How can I use vibration on android ndk?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm developing android game app using c++

I'm trying to using vibration when button is touched.

but I don't know how to use vibration on android ndk using c++.

I searched on internet how to use vibration on android ndk.

but there are only method using jni call. I don't want to using jni.

Could you give me a tip?

Comment: Refer to this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5198105/5137352
Or read this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI